# How to uninstall Archlinux?

Tags: arch-linux, dual-boot, uninstall

I have had Archlinux for quite a while dual-booted alongside my Windows 7 (bootmenu is `GRUB`), I would like to replace Arch with Ubuntu for now due to starting to develop games on Linux, but I have no idea on how to uninstall Arch.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to uninstall anything.

You simply need to install Ubuntu and once you chose the partition to install on (your current ArchLinux partition), the installer will give you the option to format it.

Comment: Thank you! Very useful as I did not think about this, I will go ahead and try :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Ubuntu live usb. Open `gparted` and format partition that you used for Arch.